# Text in floated div

Tags: css, html, text, css-float

The situation is:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#a{
    float:left;
    width:800px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}

#b{
    width:1000px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#9CC;
}
```

**The result:**
[image]

Why doesn't the text go behind **div#a** ? Why does "Some Text" behave as if **div#a** is **still in the normal flow**? How to force the text to act as expected (to go under div#a) ?

**UPDATE:**
When I mean under, I mean beneath on the Z axis, not on the Y. The div's should stay in this position, the only part that needs moving is the text.

Comment: why you are not using position?

Comment: This is the way CSS works, if you want "Some Text" to appear inside your grey div, you could put a container around it, position that relative, and then position your "Some Text" div to position absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/float

> • left
> The element generates a block box that is floated to the left.
>   Content flows on the right side of the box, starting at the top.

The content of `#b` is acting as it should. It floats to the right side of the floated element preceding it.

Thus, if you want a 'layered' effect, use a CSS declaration that will provide it properly: `position`

**Note:** to keep `#a` positioned to it's parent, rather than `<body>`:

```
#main { position:relative }
#a { position:absolute }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you float one element, the next element will "touch" it if there is place for it and it is a block level element (native or set by CSS).

If you want the elements "not" next to each other, than don't use float! Keep in mind that they have to be block level to go underneath each other.

Float does not "lift" element up, like for example `position: absolute` would do.

Comment: of course, float just exits the element out of the normal flow. See Example E from http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/ that is the principle I want div a and b to overlap on the Z-axis, but the only problem remains b's content that seems to defy its parent's flow.

Answer (score 1):

check out this:

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

I think z-index statement may also be useful

ADDENDUM

```
<style type="text/css">
<!-- 
#id {
position:relative;
}

#a{
/* float:left;  */
 position: absolute;
 top:0%;
 left0%;
width:800px;
height:150px;
background-color:#CCC;
    z-indez:1;
}

#b{
position: absolute;
 top:0%;
 left0%;
width:1000px;
height:100px;
background-color:#9CC;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

does the trick (in chrome, ff, IE6 ) I couldn't get it to work until I gave id=b a negative z index trust thats helpful

Answer (score 0):

The floated element floats to the left of non-floated elements like the blue element. To force the blue element below the floated element, you could apply `clear: left;` to it.

Answer (score 0):

If both of your div ID's have float:left assigned then the second div #b will follow suit and go beneath #a

Comment: If you remove the float:left on #a and add float:right on #b then it will drop down. You will then have to adjust the width of the two divs for it to line up

Comment: I do not want to make them inline, i want to overlap them on the Z-axis

Comment: To overlap on the Z-Axis I would then apply negative values to the top and left margin on the #b div
http://jsfiddle.net/b3Dat/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add this code:

```
float:left;
```

to #b style

Comment: does not do the job, it just acts as if I'd put clear:left: to #b. The purpose is to get the text not to "see" the div#a, and to be contained in div#b as it should normally be.

Answer (score 0):

Give display block to both #a, #b

Comment: You can use float:left; or display:block; for both #a,#b