# Why is text contained in div that follows a floated div appearing out of place?

Tags: css, css-float

[image][image]I have 4 divs in this order : #header , #content, #navigation, #footer.

```css
#header {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 10%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#content {
  background: green;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 74%;
  float: left;
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#navigation {
  background: brown;
  height: 80%;
  width: 24%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#footer {
  background: hotpink;
  height: 10%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body,html {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
 <div id="header">DEFAULT</div>
  <div id="content">FLOAT</div>
  <div id="navigation">NAVIGATION</div>
  <div id="footer">CLEAR</div>
```

I am learning css, and in this scenario my understanding is that a non floated block level div named "navigation" will move in to take the place of a left floated div "content".
The text 'NAVIGATION' inside of the div with id "navigation" is not hiding behind the #content div and is instead appearing inside of #footer div.

After going through this question [Text in floated div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530969/text-in-floated-div) I learnt that content in following div will float around this floated div.

Now since this #content div is only 75% wide, why is the NAVIGATION text not appearing right next to the #content div ? Why does it appear inside of the #footer div ?

Comment: because navigation is not floating.

Comment: this can help you understand step by step:https://stackoverflow.com/a/54299426/8620333

Comment: Hi Temani Afif, I have updated the question to include what I am seeing in my browser and have also included the developer tools snapshot which shows that the navigation div has moved up to hide behind the content div. I am not able to understand that if the navigation div was moved up to take the place of the content div, why did the text contained in navigation not move behind the content div and got hidden. Why is it not contained inside of the navigation div and is instead appearing in the footer div. I have no other CSS applied anywhere else. Also I have not included any other css file

Comment: because the navigation is 25% thus the text is overflowing ... to test what is happening, put the navigation at 100% and start decreasing the width and you will see what is happening

Comment: Thanks, I saw that if I keep the navigation width to >= 82 % then the navigation text shows up in the same line as both content & navigation divs. 1 thing that is still unclear, why is the 'navigation' text still not overlapped by content div ? I used to think that inline level elements will float around the floated elements. But here the 'navigation' text is contained inside of a block level navigation element , so why is this text still floating around the content div. I have text-align : center, this is centering the text in the area to the right of content div and not inside navigation div

Comment: all the text will wrap around float even if nested inside another div or many divs. a float element NEVER overlap inline element (such as text) and only overlap block element. that's why your float is over the navigation div but not the text inside (you can check the link I shared to better understand this)

Comment: Thanks, if that is how CSS behaves I am fine with it. I will just need to remember that inline content inside of block level element that follows a floated element will still flow around the floated element, even though its parent div doesnt flow around it. Thanks again for your patience and I will re-read the links you shared earlier. How do I select your last comment as my answer ?

Comment: you cannot select a comment as answer, will add an answer in case I don't find a good duplicate that already contain the needed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**display:inline-block is a better way to use float**

inline-block is better than float, The reason that using the float method is not suited for layout of your page is because the float CSS property was originally intended only to have text wrap around an image and is, by design, not best suited for general page layout purposes

Yo can do this, first remove

> float: left;

in #content and add

> display: inline-block;

and add

> display: inline-block;

```css
#header {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 10%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#content {
  background: green;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 74%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#navigation {
  background: brown;
  height: 80%;
  width: 24%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#footer {
  background: hotpink;
  height: 10%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body,html {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">DEFAULT</div>
<div id="content">FLOAT</div>
<div id="navigation">NAVIGATION</div>
<div id="footer">CLEAR</div>
```